# Sonar-runner failing while downloading http://localhost:9000/batch/sonar-batch -maven-compat-4.5.2.jar

Tags: sonar-runner

I am trying a Build through sonar-runner .But sonar Runner is failing while trying to Downloading this file.& i am not using maven.

```
**http://localhost:9000/batch/sonar-batch-maven-compat-4.5.2.jar**
```

Log File: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkjdQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're using an outdated version of SonarQube. Please migrate to version 5.6 (latest LTS)

Comment: Thanks Julien, but currently it is hard for me to update my sonar.  Usually we run analysis in sonar server only, but for the first time we are running it from client machine which i Windows.  The error is occurring even while ewe check sonar Runner "sonar-runner -h".

Comment: All i can hit is any other files rather than a *.jar files from server. i.e. .txt,.jpg.

Comment: I understand, but as it's a pretty old version that you're using it will be hard for someone to help you.

Comment: Hi Julian ,Thanks.    I was able to find that the http://localhost:9000/batch/*  only restricts *jar file to download. If we try download any other file extensions, it works.